# C# write datagridview data into a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a four column table in a SQL Server database. The info for the first three columns is supplied by another source. Column 4 is set to null by default.

I then have a win form with a datatable that populates with the information from the SQL Server database using the following code:

```
public DataTable populateFormList()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.sqlConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM of_formlist_raw", con);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    return dt;
}

datagridview2.DataSource = populateFormList();
datagridview2.Refresh();
```

Now that works fine in obtaining my data.

The user can then make changes to the null values in column 4.

How can I easily write these changes from the datatable back into the SQL Server table?

In other words, once the on screen datatable has additional values, how can I then store the updated information back in the SQL Server database from which it was originally obtained from?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you means database back into sql table? (close connection, close reader after using it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this and just pass `(DataTable)datagridview2.DataSource` as the data table:

```
private static void BulkInsertToSQL(DataTable dt, string tableName)
        {

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_DB))
                {
                    SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
                    sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName;

                    //if your DB col names don’t match your data table column names 100%
                    //then relate the source data table column names with the destination DB cols
                    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("DBAttributeName1", "DTColumnName1");
                    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("DBAttributeName2", "DTColumnName2");
                    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("DBAttributeName3", "DTColumnName3");
                    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("DBAttributeName4", "DTColumnName4");

                    con.Open();

                    sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options, with or without TableAdapter.

I would recommend to [read this in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0f92s97z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for TableAdapter

They're using BindingSources too, which are excellent components, easy-to-use.

Without TableAdapter, [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms233819%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the "Update Records Using Command Objects" part.

Comment: The 4th coloum is already there as stated, so I can just used table atapater and it should write the data-table information back to the sql database?